# Android multiple input q parameters in Google Translate API , with volley java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

How to send multiple q input texts? As I see, the API doesn't allow q[] type arrays, instead it uses multiple q parameters.

```
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            List<String> textString  = new ArrayList<>();
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("key", "key");
            params.put("target", "DE");          
            params.put("q", text);
            return params;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the following helper class:

```
class HttpParams extends HashMap<String, List<String>> {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public HttpParams() {
            super();
        }

        public HttpParams(int capacity) {
            super(capacity);
        }

        public HttpParams(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
            super(map);
        }

        public HttpParams(int capacity, float loadFactor) {
            super(capacity, loadFactor);
        }

        /*
         * This is the method to use for adding post parameters
         */
        public void add(String key, String value) {
            if (containsKey(key)) {
                get(key).add(value);
            }
            else {
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add(value);
                put(key, list);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Converts the Map into an application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoded string.
         */
        public byte[] encodeParameters(String paramsEncoding) {
            StringBuilder encodedParams = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : entrySet()) {
                    String key = URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), paramsEncoding);
                    for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
                        encodedParams.append(key);
                        encodedParams.append('=');
                        try {
                            encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(value, paramsEncoding));
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        encodedParams.append('&');
                    }
                }
                return encodedParams.toString().getBytes(paramsEncoding);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + paramsEncoding,     uee);
            }
        }
    }
```

and then in Main class that extends Request overrided the getBody():

```
public void volleyPost(String text,OnServiceResponseListener onServiceResponseListener){
  
        String URL = "Your Url here";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        HttpParams mParams = new HttpParams();
        mParams.add("key", "key");
        mParams.add("target", "languageCode");
      
        String wordsArray [] = text.split(",");
        for(int i = 0;i<wordsArray.length;i++) {
            mParams.add("q", wordsArray[i]);
        }

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        onServiceResponseListener.onSuccess(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                      onServiceResponseListener.onFailed(error.getMessage());
                    }
                }){


            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                if (mParams != null && mParams.size() > 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"mParams--->"+new Gson().toJson(mParams));
                    return mParams.encodeParameters(getParamsEncoding());
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```